# Spark metric system sink errors after adding hadoop-aws dependency jar to pom file

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

I'm using the HDP version 2.6.3 with the 2.2 version of Spark (not HDP cloud) and I'm trying to write to s3 from an IntelliJ project. I have no problems writing to the s3 bucket from the shell on one of my data nodes, but when I try to test my app on my local machine in IntelliJ I get an error (ERROR MetricsSystem: Sink class org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.MetricsServlet cannot be instantiated) after adding the Hadoop-aws jar dependency to my pom file.  Does anyone know if there is any nuance to how you need to add this dependency?  If I put the dependency above the spark dependencies in my pom I get different errors with missing spark classes, so it seems to matter what order you put it in.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, solved it by excluding the libraries of Jackson from the  Hadoop's dependencies.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-aws</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```